# Is there another way to demonstrate 127.0.0.1 page

Tags: hosts

I'm editing the `hosts` file by say adding `127.0.0.1 somesite.com`

When I am navigating this site (somesite.com) access to this site will be blocked.

Can I actually edit the info which will be shown in browser when it is blocked?

Comment: Sure.  You can run your own webserver on the local system.

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback address, meaning that it will attempt to open port 80 on the local machine on which the host file resides.  If you want to customize the page that is displayed then you will need to install a webserver of some variety on the same machine.